# Unity WebGL browser support

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Is there a way to detect or get a list with browsers (and versions) which are supporting Unity WebGL?

I have a few Unity WebGL games on my website and I would like to display some information to users whether (or not) their browser supports Unity WebGL games.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the actual situation of WebGL support in the main browsers and in its versions:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl

Comment: this is strictly to webgl and not unity webgl. Unity WebGL games are using the asm.js library which in IE 11 is under development

Comment: asm.js runs in all browsers. It just runs slower in some than others.